# Remove old records from join table after saving entity

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have entity class `Film`. It has a list of genres which are enum values. I store genres in separate table `film_genres` and in entity it looks like this:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Genre.class)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@CollectionTable(name = "film_genre")
@Column(name = "genre", nullable = false)
private List<Genre> genres;
```

If I try to update some film and remove genre, after saving I need to remove old genres from `film_genres`.

I tried to add cascade removing `@Cascade(CascadeType.REMOVE)` to this field in entity, but it doesn't work. How can I remove old genres when save `Film`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use @PreUpdate or @PrePersist method in your entity and do anything you want